# Assigning 'this' to a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, this

I'm taking an object oriented approach with Javascript, for two reasons. One, because it helps me learn, and two, just in case my code is to be distributed.

I already have assigning functions to variables and using `this` for public variables. I'm running into problems using `this`, however. When I'm in a "private" function, `this` refers to a different scope, and I can't access the variables under `this`. I'll illustrate my point.

```
var ClassObject = function() {
  this.var1 = 'Hello';

  var var2 = 786;

  this.func1 = function() {
    alert(this.var1); // Alerts Hello
    alert(var2); // Alerts 786
  }

  var func2 = function() {
    alert(this.var1); // Alerts undefined
    alert(var2); // Alerts 786
  }
}
```

The only way I've found to give `func2` access to `this.var1` was to make another variable assigned to `this`: `var c = this`. Is this the best way to go about this task, or even widely acceptable? Can anybody offer a better solution?

Thank you all.

Comment: Short answer: yes, this is perfectly acceptable. I've seen the variable `self` used for that purpose: `var self = this;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is accepted practice. See [this article](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this) on scope or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope).

Reading up on **closure** may also be helpful.

Comment: Your links were very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: The blog post has been moved to https://www.jackfranklin.co.uk/blog/javascript-variable-scope-this/

Comment: Another thing to note is that `this` works differently with arrow functions. look at the explanation: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp

Answer (score 3):

The value of `this` is set by the javascript interpreter on every single function call including when calling your private functions.  The rules are fairly simple:

1. If calling `object.method()`, then `this` is set to the object inside the method.
2. If calling a normal function (whether global or local) like `fn()`, `this` is set to the global object (which is usually `window` in a browser).
3. When using `.apply()` or `.call()`, `this` is set to the first argument to those functions (e.g. you can control what it is set to by what you pass to `.apply()` or `.call()`.

Thus, when you call your private functions, you're getting option 2.  If you want access to the `this` of your object, you have these three options:

1. Make those private functions methods (they will no longer be private then) and invoke them as methods like `this.func2()` so the javascript interpreter sets `this` for you.
2. Use `.call()` or `.apply()` like `func2.call(this)` to instruct the interpreter to set `this` as you desire.
3. Store the value of `this` in a local variable before calling `func1()` with something like `var self = this` so you can refer to `self` inside `func1()` via the closure.  This is done quite commonly in javascript (takes advantage of how closures allow access to parent scope variables).

Comment: I haven't yet looked into `.call()` or `.apply()`, but I will now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want to unless you do use something like setting it to another variable.  So either restructure everything so you dont have to do it, or just use the variable.  I'd say it's acceptable to use the variable

Comment: Well, that was quick and easy. Thank you all, @Casey and TMP, and everyone else.